# Toggle the height of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I would like a link that says 'show more' that when clicked expands the height of another div to reveal all the content. Once the div is showing all the content I'd like the link to change to 'show less' and upon being clicked do the reverse.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't work for some reason, please can someone help?

This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-content').css('height', '400px');
  $('.entry-content').css('overflow', 'hidden');
 $('.show-more').click(function() {
  $('.entry-content').animate({
    'height': 'auto'
  }, 500);
  $('.show_more').html('Show Less');
  $('.show_more').addClass('show_less');
  $('.show_more').removeClass('show_more');
});
$('.show-less').click(function() {
  $('.entry-content').animate({
    'height': '400px'
  }, 500);
  $('.show_less').html('Show More');
  $('.show_less').addClass('show_more');
  $('.show_less').removeClass('show_less');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  Curabitur sed enim sit amet nibh vulputate efficitur nec eget nulla. Vestibulum vel pulvinar magna. Etiam viverra vulputate lectus. Etiam dictum maximus ligula sed efficitur. Donec in dictum purus. Sed consequat quam eu eleifend convallis. Donec sapien
  augue, volutpat ac nibh ac, molestie vulputate neque. Morbi eu fermentum est, eget vulputate quam. Phasellus et ante ipsum. Nullam tempus neque augue, nec accumsan erat hendrerit vel. Proin dolor sapien, pulvinar at rutrum quis, scelerisque vel ipsum.
  Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
</div>

<div class="another-div-elsewhere">
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing `#show-less` - looks like you're trying to toggle the show more/less, but code assumes two buttons.

Comment: You need to include the show-more and show-less click events inside $.ready

Comment: you need to wrap those clicks inside the `$(document).ready(function(){)};`

Comment: I've moved the click functions inside the document ready function but that sadly didn't work either :( I read somewhere that $() should be replaced with jQuery() is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-content').css({'height':'40px','overflow': 'hidden'});


  $('.show-more').on('click',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('less')){
      $('.entry-content').animate({
      'height': '40px'
      }, 500);
      $(this).html("Show More")
    }
    else{
       $('.entry-content').animate({
      'height': $(".entry-content").get(0).scrollHeight
      }, 500);
      $(this).html("Show Less")
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('less');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  Curabitur sed enim sit amet nibh vulputate efficitur nec eget nulla. Vestibulum vel pulvinar magna. Etiam viverra vulputate lectus. Etiam dictum maximus ligula sed efficitur. Donec in dictum purus. Sed consequat quam eu eleifend convallis. Donec sapien
  augue, volutpat ac nibh ac, molestie vulputate neque. Morbi eu fermentum est, eget vulputate quam. Phasellus et ante ipsum. Nullam tempus neque augue, nec accumsan erat hendrerit vel. Proin dolor sapien, pulvinar at rutrum quis, scelerisque vel ipsum.
  Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
</div>

<div class="another-div-elsewhere">
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issues seem to be you're attaching the `$.click()` event on id `#show-more` and `#show-less` but you never create `#show-less`... you toggle the class `.show_more` and `.show_less`. I just left that `$.click()` selector alone, and am toggling a class `.open` to determine the state of the link/text, and update the link text and text height based on that.

You can chain/combine a lot of these commands, and use variables to save jquery some work from having to rerun the selectors.

I also changed the static `400px` height to be half of the height of the `.entry-content` area, since `400px` didn't work in this demo. You can change `staticHeight` back to `400px` if it works for you, or modify what I used to fit your needs.

```js
var $content = $('.entry-content'),
    contentHeight = $content.outerHeight(),
    $showMore = $('#show-more'),
    staticHeight = contentHeight / 2;

$content.attr('data-height',contentHeight).css({
  'height': staticHeight,
  'overflow':'hidden'
});

$showMore.on('click',function() {
  var height, text;
  if ($showMore.hasClass('open')) {
    $showMore.removeClass('open');
    height = staticHeight;
    text = 'Show More';
  } else {
    $showMore.addClass('open');
    height = contentHeight;
    text = 'Show Less';
  }
  $content.animate({
    'height': height
  }, 500);
  $showMore.html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
Curabitur sed enim sit amet nibh vulputate efficitur nec eget nulla. Vestibulum vel pulvinar magna. Etiam viverra vulputate lectus. Etiam dictum maximus ligula sed efficitur. Donec in dictum purus. Sed consequat quam eu eleifend convallis. Donec sapien augue, volutpat ac nibh ac, molestie vulputate neque. Morbi eu fermentum est, eget vulputate quam. Phasellus et ante ipsum. Nullam tempus neque augue, nec accumsan erat hendrerit vel. Proin dolor sapien, pulvinar at rutrum quis, scelerisque vel ipsum. Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
</div>

<div class="another-div-elsewhere">
<a href="#" id="show-more">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.read-more').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.details').show();
      $('.summary').hide();
    })
    $('.read-less').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.summary').show();
      $('.details').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s...</p>
  <span class="read-more">
   <a href="#">Show More....</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="details">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <span class="read-less">
   <a href="#">Show Less....</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but sadly that isn't going to work. I'm using .entry-content because that's what's output in Wordpress so I don't want to include any additional divs. I just want to animate the height of that one.

Answer (score 0):

well first you had some problems in class/id usage

and the other thing is that animating height to auto is not [possible](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/)! there are other (like CSS) ways of doing this but here is a working sample of what you were trying to do. i hope it helps :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-content').css('height', '100px');
  $('.entry-content').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

$('#show_more').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('show_more')){
       $(this).html('Show Less');
       $('.entry-content').animate({
          'height': '200px'
       }, 500);
  }
  else{
      $(this).html('Show More');
      $('.entry-content').animate({
          'height': '100px'
      }, 500);
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('show_less');
  $(this).toggleClass('show_more');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  Curabitur sed enim sit amet nibh vulputate efficitur nec eget nulla. Vestibulum vel pulvinar magna. Etiam viverra vulputate lectus. Etiam dictum maximus ligula sed efficitur. Donec in dictum purus. Sed consequat quam eu eleifend convallis. Donec sapien
  augue, volutpat ac nibh ac, molestie vulputate neque. Morbi eu fermentum est, eget vulputate quam. Phasellus et ante ipsum. Nullam tempus neque augue, nec accumsan erat hendrerit vel. Proin dolor sapien, pulvinar at rutrum quis, scelerisque vel ipsum.
  Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
  Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
   Cras arcu nulla, placerat ac arcu vitae, iaculis maximus nisi. Nulla tincidunt, nisi id ultrices tempor, diam ipsum sollicitudin neque, ac consequat libero nulla eu diam.
 Curabitur sed enim sit amet nibh vulputate efficitur nec eget nulla. Vestibulum vel pulvinar magna. Etiam viverra vulputate lectus. Etiam dictum maximus ligula sed efficitur. Donec in dictum purus. Sed consequat quam eu eleifend convallis. Donec sapien
  augue, volutpat ac nibh ac, molestie vulputate neque. Morbi eu fermentum est, eget vulputate quam. Phasellus et ante ipsum. Nullam tempus neque augue, nec accumsan erat hendrerit vel. Proin dolor sapien, pulvinar at rutrum quis, scelerisque vel ipsum.
</div>

<div class="another-div-elsewhere">
  <a href="#" id="show_more" class="show_more">Show More</a>
</div>
```